# Variable scope in ajax GET and POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

We recently observed a behavior when using jQuery ajax and would like to verify if it's rational.

For example, imagine codes below:

```
function validate(e, inurl, formid, foo) {
    var v = $("#" + formid).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: inurl,
        type: 'POST',  // *** type here matters
        data: v,
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function (data) {
            // *** e, inurl, formid, including v would all be undefined here
            // *** however, if ajax call type is GET, those variables would be valid
            // *** on the other hand, foo as a callback is preserved regardless
            if (foo)
                foo(data);
        }
    });    
}
```

Is this a designed behavior so we are bound to use GET if we need to preserve those variables? If so, any related documentation would be appreciated.

Comment: A simple way to find out would be to run it, and see if they still exist after the call. I suggest learning about function and variable scope.

Comment: "We recently observed a behavior" — You must have misinterpreted what you saw. That isn't how JavaScript works.

Comment: Do you know that Ajax runs asynchronously ! means in your success function you can only access global variables v will for sure be undefined,e inurl formid and foo will be undefined unless they're global variables regardless you use get or post method

Comment: In this context there is no difference. See https://jsfiddle.net/nivas/3kjo4hg9/. Hit https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts separately from the browser once if you get a mixed content warning.

Comment: @lyz — No. That isn't how JavaScript works. Look up closures.

Comment: @Quentin I'm not expert of JavaScript but I'm pretty sure in this example you can't access those variables I don't see any function closure here and no extra param is passed to the callback

Comment: @lyz — There is a function expression on the line starting `success`. There's your closure. The function `validate` ends, but it has closed over the anonymous function and its variables are still available to that anonymous function.

Comment: @Quentin so you mean v variable should be accessible in success function ? I'm gonna try this tomorrow but I doubt it will work

Comment: @lyz — http://jsbin.com/rokuli/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Actually all of them would be available in the `success` callback. Why you think otherwise ? (*demo that exhibit this behavior?*).

Comment: @Quentin thank you, I was mistaken in fact, just reviewed about closures in js and you're right, you taught me something :)

Answer (score 0):

After playing around it a little, I figured I was using a wrong way to testify if those variables are valid or not. What I did is I put a breakpoint right before `if (foo)` and use browser's console to inspect those variables ***without*** any statement accessing them within the `success` callback. Because even though ajax runs asynchronously, as long as it's within its parent function, it would have access to that function's variables based on javascript closure (Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp). But this is true only if they are referenced within the callback, e.g. `console.log(e)`. This way, they were captured before parent function returns. And when the callback is triggered later, those variables would still be valid. Hope this clears confusion. Thanks for all comments.